# How to run shell commands in C file and assign a integer in a variable?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am trying to make an C file, in which I need to run some shell commands.

**My task**,

If the username is `jhamb`, then perform some task, otherwise perform other task.

**My code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
     char username[10];
     system("echo $USER | username");
     if(username == "jhamb")  {
         //PERFORM SPECIFIC TASKS
     }
     else {  
          // PERFORM OTHER TASKS
     }        
}
```

But it didn't give appropriate output. Tell me how to correct this code.

**Edit No. 1**

`cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep service | grep soft | awk '{print $4}'`. This script gives output `13000`.

Now I want to store this 13000 in a variable.

How can I do this in C file?

Comment: You can't compare strings like this... `username == "jhamb"`. Use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for comparing C strings.

Comment: When did `username` get set?

Comment: I so miss perl when such a functionality is needed

Comment: @jhamb: for edit no. 1, see the answers below that use popen.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`getenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) to get environment variables such as `USER`.

Use the [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function to compare strings for equality.

Comment: I want to get any integer in a variable then How can I do that ?

For example : `cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep service | grep soft | awk '{print $4}'` It is an integer, how can I assign in any variable ?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h> //for popen
#include <string.h>    

char* cmd_system(const char* command)
{
    char* result = "";
    FILE *fpRead;
    fpRead = popen(command, "r");
    char buf[1024];
    memset(buf,'\0',sizeof(buf));
    while(fgets(buf,1024-1,fpRead)!=NULL)
    {
        result = buf;
    }
    if(fpRead!=NULL)
       pclose(fpRead);
    return result;
}
```

use this function, and you can get the return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *username;
    username = getenv("USER");
    if(strcmp(username,"jhamb") == 0){
        printf("Yes\n");
    }else{
        printf("No\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a linux command,you can try the function system(),the summary of this funcion can be found [herer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)I also write a program to show it.The program show how to use the comand "ls"

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main ()
    {
       int i;
       char *command;
       command = "ls";
       if(system(NULL))   printf("ok\n");
       else  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       i=system(command);
       printf(the value returned was:%d\n",i);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry,now I have show you the code,the system function dose the same thing as the popen function.

Comment: Can you give me answer of Edit no. 1.

Comment: `cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep service | grep soft | awk '{print $4}'`. Output of above script is 13000. Now I have to store this 13000 in a variable in C. How can I do that ?

Comment: I think getevn can help you,then you need transform the string into integer type.

Comment: No, their is something wrong in this. It shows Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I am also searching the function that performs this task for me.

Comment: well,I want you show me the program showing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `getlogin_r()` of `unistd.h` to get the current user name and then use `strcmp` on it?

See the man pages for `getlogin_r`

Answer (score 0):

Your code pipes the results of `echo $USER` into the BASH command `username`. That is different from the C variable `username`.

To capture the output of a system command, use `popen`. [This page](http://www.sw-at.com/blog/2011/03/23/popen-execute-shell-command-from-cc/) has a good example. For your purposes, something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    char username[50];
    FILE *in;
    extern FILE *popen();

    if(!(in = popen("echo $USER","r"))) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    fgets(username, sizeof(username), in);

    if(strcmp(username,"jhamb") == 0) {
        // proceed
    }
}
```

Note, in particular, that you should use `strcmp` to compare strings. Strings themselves are just pointers, and using `==` tests whether the pointers point to the same place in memory, not whether the strings are identical.